# How do I use list monad inside of ReaderT?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

How do I use `Reader`/`ReaderT` to `ask` for a list type, e.g. `[(Int, Int)]` and then perform calculations inside the list monad (of the type that was `ask`ed for)?

My broken code follows, shortened for clarity:

```
attempt :: Int -> Int -> ReaderT [(Int,Int)] [] [[Int]]
attempt start end =
  do  (s0, e0) <- ask
      return [0]
```

To give you an idea of what I'm trying to do, here is the same function, using the list monad but not Reader:

```
paths :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
paths edges start end =
  if start == end
    then return [end]
    else do   (s0, e0) <- edges
              guard $ s0 == start
              subpath <- paths edges e0 end
              return $ s0 : subpath
```

I'm using ReaderT because I'm learning monad transformers. It's part of a larger problem using both Reader and Writer and list monad to implement paths.

Comment: Could you just use `Reader [(Int,Int)] [[Int]]` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick here is to use lift to convert a list monad (ie an `[a]`) into a `ReaderT env []` by using `lift`:

```
lift :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => m a -> t m a
```

or specialized to your monad stack:

```
lift :: [a] -> ReaderT [(Int,Int)] [] a
```

`ask` returns the state (ie `[(Int, Int)]`) wrapped in the `ReaderT` monad eg:

```
ask :: ReaderT [(Int, Int)] [] [(Int, Int)]
```

We want to convert that into another value in the same monad but with the type:

```
??? :: ReaderT [(Int, Int)] [] (Int, Int)
```

So the alternatives are tracked by the monad instead of in the output. Consider the basic function `>>=`:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

You should be able to see we have all the pieces required. Using `ask >>= lift`:

1. The first argument is `ReaderT [(Int, Int)] [] [(Int, Int)]`, meaning `a` is `[(Int, Int)]`, and `m` is `ReaderT [(Int, Int)] []`
2. We want the result `m b` to be `ReaderT [(Int, Int)] [] (Int, Int)`, so `b` is `(Int, Int)`
3. So the function needs the type `[(Int, Int)] -> ReaderT [(Int, Int)] [] (Int, Int)`. If you replace the `a` in the `lift` function with `(Int, Int)`, it is a perfect match, meaning the expression `ask >>= lift` does what you want.

The other mistake you had was the output type of the `ReaderT` monad - as it contained a list monad you didn't need to wrap the result in another pair of brackets. A `ReaderT state []` already contains the concept of multiple results, and a single result in this case is a `[Int]` showing the graph path.

Here is the working code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
module Main where
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Applicative


paths :: Int -> Int -> ReaderT [(Int,Int)] [] [Int]
paths start end = do
  if start == end
     then return [end]
     else do
      (s0, e0) <- ask >>= lift
      guard $ s0 == start
      (s0 :) <$> paths e0 end


input :: [(Int, Int)]
input = [(1,2), (2,7), (3,4), (7, 3), (7, 5), (5, 3)]

test :: [[Int]]
test = runReaderT (paths 2 4) input


> test
[[2,7,3,4],[2,7,5,3,4]]
```

I hope that explains it clearly. In this situation, I would probably just stick with the original solution (using `Reader` by itself is normally not very useful), but it is good to know how to understand and manipulate the types of monads and monad transformers.