# Use list monad inside monad transformer type classes?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, monadplus

My goal is to create a function that uses the list monad inside either a ReaderT WriterT stack, or a RWS stack. More generally, how do I use the list monad inside mtl typeclasses such as MonadReader, MonadWriter?

Why am I trying to do this? This problem is an exercise in [Beginning Haskell](http://www.apress.com/9781430262503). It asks me to "use functionality from both MonadReader and MonadWriter wrapping the base list monad. To check that the function is general, use two different monads to [test] the requested functionality: `ReaderT r (WriterT w []) a` and `RWST r w s m a`"  So the book implies this is possible.

I can't figure out how to 'tell' the compiler to use the list monad. If I use `ask >>= lift` or `ask >>= lift . lift` I can get either the 2 level stack (`RWST []`) or 3 level stack (`ReaderT WriterT []`) to work, but not both.

The focus of my question:

```
pathImplicitStack' start end | start == end = tell [end]
pathImplicitStack' start end =
  do  (s0, e0) <- ask >>= lift
      guard $ s0 == start
      tell [start]
      pathImplicitStack' e0 end
```

Additionally, I'd like to know how to type the function. My best attempt so far looks something like `pathImplicitStack' :: (MonadReader [(Int, Int)] m, MonadWriter [Int] m, MonadPlus m) => Int -> Int -> m ()`  I know this isn't right, the list monad is probably missing. Also, I think MonadPlus might be useful in the type signature, but I'm not quite sure.

This line: `do  (s0, e0) <- ask >>= lift` is the one giving me trouble. I've tried 0, 1, and 2 lifts without success. I'd like to `ask` for a `[(Int, Int)]` and then use the list monad to process just a `(Int, Int)` (and let the list monad try all possibilities for me).

As part of the exercise, I need to be able to call `pathImplicitStack'` with both of these functions (or very similar functions):

```
pathImplicitRW :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
pathImplicitRW edges start end = execWriterT rdr
  where rdr = runReaderT (pathImplicitStack' start end) edges :: WriterT [Int] [] ()

pathImplicitRWS :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
pathImplicitRWS edges start end = map snd exec
  where exec = execRWST (pathImplicitStack' start end) edges ()
```

This is related to my previous question: [How do I use list monad inside of ReaderT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178800/how-do-i-use-list-monad-inside-of-readert)

The whole file for easy testing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Foo where

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.RWS

graph1 :: [(Int, Int)]
graph1 = [(2013,501),(2013,1004),(501,2558),(1004,2558)]


pathImplicitRW :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
pathImplicitRW edges start end = execWriterT rdr
  where rdr = runReaderT (pathImplicitStack' start end) edges :: WriterT [Int] [] ()

pathImplicitRWS :: [(Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
pathImplicitRWS edges start end = map snd exec
  where exec = execRWST (pathImplicitStack' start end) edges ()

pathImplicitStack' :: (MonadReader [(Int, Int)] m, MonadWriter [Int] m, MonadPlus m) => Int -> Int -> [m ()]
pathImplicitStack' start end | start == end = tell [end]
pathImplicitStack' start end =
  do  (s0, e0) <- ask >>= lift
      guard $ s0 == start
      tell [start]
      pathImplicitStack' e0 end
```

**edit**

Based on John L's feedback I tried

```
pathImplicitStack' :: (MonadReader [(Int, Int)] (t []), MonadWriter [Int] (t []), MonadPlus (t []), MonadTrans t) => Int -> Int -> t [] ()
pathImplicitStack' start end | start == end = tell [end]
pathImplicitStack' start end =
  do  (s0, e0) <- ask >>= lift
      guard $ s0 == start
      tell [start]
      pathImplicitStack' e0 end
```

but as he pointed out, it can only be used with one monad transformer to wrap the list monad, i.e. RSWT, and is not usable with ReaderT WriterT. So this is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: `MonadPlus` is basically the "list monad" type class.  For example: `cons a as = return a \`mplus\` as` and `nil = mzero`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the basic problem with doing this within the requirements of the question is that there is no MTL library function for lifting from a list monad that may be arbitrary levels down.  However, you can "cheat" a bit: The `MonadPlus` instance for the combined `Monad` *is* inherited from the underlying list monad regardless of the depth, and you can use it to generate the needed action:

```
  do  (s0, e0) <- ask >>= msum . map return
```

There is then also an error in the type signature, which needs to be changed to:

```
pathImplicitStack' :: (MonadReader [(Int, Int)] m, MonadWriter [Int] m, MonadPlus m) => Int -> Int -> m ()
```

EDIT: Actually on second thought this is not actually cheating.  It's just using the `MonadPlus` API for chaining alternative actions instead of using the underlying list monad directly.

Comment: That worked, thanks!
I don't consider MonadPlus cheating either. I've been exposed to it in the book, so seems like fair game to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the difficulty here is that you're mixing up layers of the monad.  Looking at

```
pathImplicitStack' :: (MonadReader [(Int, Int)] m, MonadWriter [Int] m, MonadPlus m) => Int -> Int -> [m ()]
```

This function returns a list of `m ()` computations, however the `ask >>= lift` (and your earlier question) are presuming that `List` is the base monad upon which you stack extra transformers.  If you want to use `List` as the base monad, you'll need to change the type of `pathImplicitStack'`

```
pathImplicitStack' :: (MonadReader [(Int, Int)] (t []), MonadWriter [Int] (t []), MonadPlus (t [])) => Int -> Int -> t [] ()
```

But even this isn't quite general enough, because this only allows adding a single transformer on top of the List.  You could use a type-operator library to combine two monad transformers into a single transformer, but that seems a bit complicated for this.

Here is one option: use Identity as the base monad and perform your list operations outside that monad stack.  (warning, all code untested, it may not even compile)

```
pathImplicitStack' :: (MonadReader [(Int, Int)] m, MonadWriter [Int] m, MonadPlus m) => Int -> Int -> m ()
pathImplicitStack' start end | start == end = tell [end]
pathImplicitStack' start end =
  do  (s0, e0) <- ask >>= lift
      edges <- filter ((== start) . fst) <$> ask
      let m (s0,e0) = tell [s0] >> pathImplicitStack' e0 end
      mapM_ m edges
```

There is another option.  You can use `ListT` or `LogicT` as the outer transformer, letting you use this function (or something like it):

```
pathImplicitStack'2 :: (MonadReader [(Int, Int)] m, MonadWriter [Int] m) => Int -> Int -> ListT m ()
pathImplicitStack'2 start end | start == end = tell [end]
pathImplicitStack'2 start end =
  do  (s0, e0) <- ask
      guard $ s0 == start
      tell [start]
      pathImplicitStack'2 e0 end
-- if you have MonadReader/MonadWriter instances for ListT in scope, I think this will
-- work.  But if they aren't available, you will need to use `lift ask` and 
-- `lift (tell ...)`
```

I would almost certainly choose the first approach.

Comment: Sadly, the exercise as presented to me in the book (see my edit) wants my function to be usable by both a ReaderT WriterT stack, and a RSWT, and it wants them to be 'wrapping the base list monad'. So for the purpose of the exercise, the first approach isn't general enough. The book hasn't introduced any type-operator libraries, so I'm pretty sure that's not the 'answer'. And if list is not the inner monad, I won't get the proper answer `[[Int]]` out of the Writer.

Comment: @DanielK you could simply replace `lift` with `liftBase` (from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-base) in your function and that would work.  But I don't think `liftBase` is part of the expected answer either.