# An alternative Alternative for lists

Tags: list, haskell, applicative, alternative-functor, monadplus

A few times now, I've found myself defining:

```hs
(<?>) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[] <?> ys = ys
xs <?> _  = xs
```

This is an associative operation, of course, and the empty list `[]` is both left- and right-identity. It functions like Python's `or`.

It seems to me that this would make a nice `(<|>)`, better than `(++)` would. Choosing the first nonempty list feels more like what I would expect from a typeclass named `Alternative` than concatenating lists. Admittedly, it doesn't fit `MonadPlus` as well, but I think that a small price to pay for salvation. We already have `(++)` and `(<>)` in the standard library; do we need another synonym, or would a new function (as far as I can tell) be more helpful?

I was at first thinking this might be a good `Alternative` instance for `ZipList`, but the discussion following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220076/5499914) on the relevant question has convinced me otherwise. Other than backwards-compatibility and keeping `MonadPlus` sensible, what arguments are there for the current instance rather than this new one?

Comment: The question is does it satisfy the `some v = (:) <$> v <*> many v` and `many v = some v <|> pure []` laws (with a certain `<$>` and `<*>` that should thus satisfy the laws for a functor and applicative, etc). I'm not convinced. You of course do not need to use the `<*>` defined on `[]` (you can use another one), but then still it has to be lawful.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem From [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#some), it looks to me like `some` and `many` are defined in a way that guarantees this.

Comment: Synonyms are good: you can use whichever one comes to mind first without getting it wrong. Making `(<|>)` different from `mplus` and `(++)` and `(<>)` would not be helpful. It would be disastrous.

Comment: As you commented in my deleted post `ZipList` does have a different `Alternative` which doesn't hold your definition. That makes me think that `some` or `many` has something to do with this. Your definition does hold `Monoid` laws, which apparently are the only one that matters https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Alternative_and_MonadPlus

Comment: @lsmor The motivation for picking that `Alternative` instance for `ZipList` was having it follow what [the Typeclassopedia calls](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Laws_6) the left distribution law. See [GHC issue #13520](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/13520) for the relevant discussion.

Comment: @duplode `ZipList` Instance makes complete sense, But OP proposal do satisfy `Monoid` laws as well as left/right zero w.r.t. `<*>`, and IMHO It makes more sense for `[]` than concatenation... but is just my opinion. I wonder if there are strong arguments in favor of current list Instance

Comment: what you propose is Prolog's "committed choice". cf. `condA` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848902/849891), `(coundA (g) (f)) x = (g ~~> true ||~ f) x == g x <?> f x`. Naturally `++` is the regular non-deterministic choice, `(condE (g) (f)) x = (g ||: f) x == g x ++ f x` (with the operators from the cited answer). there's two more "conditionals" i.e. choice ops there, `condU` and `condI`, equivalently expressed as `a +! b == take 1 a <?> b` and `a +/ b == concat $ transpose [a,b]`. the last one evocative of zipping, i.e. ZipList ties up with all this as well somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is tricky to give your question a straight answer. Considered in isolation, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with your proposed instance. Still, there are quite a few things that can be said in support of the existing `Alternative` instance for lists.

---

> Admittedly, it doesn't fit `MonadPlus` as well, but I think that a small price to pay for salvation.

One problem with going down that route is that `Alternative` is meant to capture the same general concept that `MonadPlus` does, but in terms of `Applicative` rather than `Monad`. To quote [a relevant answer by Edward Kmett](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168111/2751851):

> Effectively, `Alternative` is to `Applicative` what `MonadPlus` is to `Monad`.

From that point of view, having mismatching `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` instances is confusing and misleading, much like the analogous situation with `Applicative` and `Monad` instances would be.

(A possible counter to this argument would be wondering why do we need to care about `MonadPlus` anyway, given that it expresses the same concepts and offers essentially the same methods as `Alternative`. It should be noted, though, that the `MonadPlus` laws are stronger than the `Alternative` ones, as the relevant interactions of its methods with the `Monad` ones aren't expressible in terms of `Alternative`. That being so, `MonadPlus` still has meaning of its own, and a conceivable outcome of a hypothetical reform of the classes would be retaining it as a laws-only class, as discussed for instance in the final section of [this answer by Antal Spector-Zabusky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081604/2751851).)

Given such considerations, in what follows I will assume the continued relevance of `MonadPlus`. That makes writing the rest of this answer much easier, as `MonadPlus` is the original expression of the general concept in Haskell, and so it is pretty much necessary to refer to it while tracing the origin of the list instance of `Alternative`.

---

> It seems to me that this would make a nice `(<|>)`, better than `(++)` would. Choosing the first nonempty list feels more like what I would expect from a typeclass named `Alternative` than concatenating lists.

Tracing the roots of `MonadPlus` and `Alternative`, though, shows that the concatenating list instance is not just well-established, but even paradigmatic. For instance, quoting the classic paper by Hutton and Meijer, [*Monadic parsing in Haskell* (1998)](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/pearl.pdf), p. 4:

> That is, a type constructor `m` is a member of the class `MonadZero` if it is a member of the class `Monad`, and if it is also equipped with a value `zero` of the specified type. In a similar way, the class `MonadPlus` builds upon the class `MonadZero` by adding a `(++)` operation of the specified type.

(Note that the authors do use `(++)` as their name for `mplus`.)

The notion `mplus` captures here is that of non-deterministic choice: if computations `u` and `v` each have some possible results, the possible results of `` u `mplus` v `` will be all of the possible results of `u` and `v`. The most elementary realisation of that is through `MonadPlus` for lists, though the idea extends to cover other non-determinism monads, such as Hutton and Meijer's `Parser`:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a,String)])
```

To spin it another way, we might describe non-deterministic choice as inclusive disjunction, while the operation you propose is a form of (left-biased) exclusive choice. (It is worth noting that Hutton and Meijer also define `(+++)`, a deterministic choice operator for their `Parser` which is rather like your operator except that it only picks the first result of the first successsful computation.)

A further relevant observation: one of the monad transformers from [*transformers*](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.10.1/docs/html/libraries/transformers-0.5.6.2/index.html) that doesn't have a [*mtl*](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.10.1/docs/html/libraries/mtl-2.2.2/index.html) class counterpart is `ListT`. That is so because the class which generalises the `ListT` functionality is precisely `MonadPlus`. Quoting [a Gabriella Gonzalez comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195617/use-list-monad-inside-monad-transformer-type-classes#comment37376267_24195617):

> `MonadPlus` is basically the "list monad" type class. For example: `` cons a as = return a `mplus` as `` and `nil = mzero`.

Note that the brokenness of *transformers*' `ListT` is not an issue. In general, the various formulations of `ListT`-done-right are equipped with a concatenating `MonadPlus` instance (examples: [one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-1.0.4/docs/ListT.html), [two](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes.html#t:ListT), [three](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict-0.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Logic.html)).

---

So much for reasons why we might want to leave the `Alternative []` and `MonadPlus []` instances as they are. Still, this answer would be lacking if it didn't recognise that, [as Will Ness reminds us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860124/an-alternative-alternative-for-lists#comment109542322_61860124), there are multiple reasonable notions of choice, and your operator embodies one of them.

The "official" laws (that is, the ones actually mentioned by the documentation) of `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` don't specify a single notion of choice. That being so, we end up with both non-deterministic (e.g. `mplus @[]`) and deterministic (e.g. `mplus @Maybe`) choice instances under the same `Alternative`/`MonadPlus` umbrella. Furthermore, if one chose to disregard my argument above and replace `mplus @[]` with your operator, nothing in the "official" laws would stop them. Over the years, there has been some talk of [reforming `MonadPlus`](https://wiki.haskell.org/MonadPlus_reform_proposal) by splitting it into classes with extra laws, in order to separate the different notions of choice. The odds of such a reform actually happening, though, don't seem high (lots of churn for relatively little practical benefit).

For the sake of contrast, it is interesting to consider the near-semiring interpretation, which is one of the reimaginings of `MonadPlus` and `Alternative` that might be invoked in a hypothetical class hierarchy reform. For a fully fleshed account of it, see Rivas, Jaskelioff and Schrijvers, [*A Unified View of Monadic and Applicative Non-determinism* (2018)](https://www.fceia.unr.edu.ar/%7Emauro/pubs/UnifiedND.pdf). For our current purposes, it suffices to note the interpretation tailors the classes to non-deterministic choice by adding, to the monoid laws, "left zero" and "left distribution" laws for `Alternative`...

```
empty <*> x = empty
(f <|> g) <*> x = (f <*> x) <|> (g <*> x)
```

... as well as for `MonadPlus`:

```
mzero >>= k = mzero
(m1 `mplus` m2) >>= k = (m1 >>= k) `mplus` (m2 >>= k)
```

(Those `MonadPlus` laws are strictly stronger than their `Alternative` counterparts.)

In particular, your choice operator follows the purported `Alternative` left distribution law, but not the `MonadPlus` one. In that respect, it is similar to `mplus @Maybe`. `MonadPlus` left distribution makes it difficult (probably impossible, though I don't have a proof at hand right now) to drop any results in `mplus`, as we can't tell, on the right hand side of the law, whether `m1 >>= k` or `m2 >>= k` will fail without inspecting the results of `m1` and `m2`. To conclude this answer with something tangible, here is a demonstration of this point:

```
-- Your operator.
(<?>) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[] <?> ys = ys
xs <?> _  = xs

filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p xs = xs >>= \x -> if p x then [x] else []
-- If MonadPlus left distribution holds, then:
-- filter' p (xs `mplus` ys) = filter' p xs `mplus` filter' p ys
```

```
GHCi> filter' even ([1,3,5] <|> [0,2,4])
[0,2,4]
GHCi> filter' even [1,3,5] <|> filter' even [0,2,4]
[0,2,4]
GHCi> filter' even ([1,3,5] <?> [0,2,4])
[]
GHCi> filter' even [1,3,5] <?> filter' even [0,2,4]
[0,2,4]
```